# Force div's height expand with it's container

Tags: css

How can I force `.content` div to expand height to 100% without scroll on page

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
body , html { height:100% ; padding:0px ; margin:0px}

.container { width:50%;height:100%; background:#e0e0e0} 
.header { background-color:#ff0066 ; padding:5px 0px 5px 5px}
.content { background-color:#333;color:#fff ; padding:20px}
.footer { background-color:#ff0066 ; padding:5px 0px 5px 5px;}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqbr78wa/)

Comment: @CrazyPaste it works . but page getting scroll-bar

Comment: use `calc` but you need to give fix `height` for `header` and `footer` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqbr78wa/2/)

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes I have found you solution on fiddle . ready for mark as asnwer

Comment: .content { background-color:#333;color:#fff; height: 100%;  padding:20px; overflow: hidden;}  I'm not sure if you'll lose content, though.  Worth a shot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/wqbr78wa/2/

use `calc` but you need to give fix `height` for `header` and `footer` fiddle

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #e0e0e0
}
.header {
  background-color: #ff0066;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
  height: 30px;
}
.content {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
}
.footer {
  background-color: #ff0066;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would you do it if the height of both the header and footer containers are unknown or dynamic?

Comment: you will need to use javascript or jquery @Sai

Comment: - Hey I am am trying just that but I am missing something. here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wqbr78wa/6/ . do you mind looking at it . Please and thanks

Comment: @Sai This was my solution to your problem. `$( ".content" ).outerHeight( function() {
  var height = $(this).parent().innerHeight();
  $(this).siblings().each( function() {
    height -= $(this).outerHeight();
  })
  return height;
});` If you want it to update it when the window resizes, you would need to call the function then as well.

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqbr78wa/7/) @Sai dont add css styles using jQuery add in styles on resize is also included

Comment: Thanks to both Vitorino Fernandes and Marcelo. I had to wrap my head around the outer height and inner height concept.